# Flutter - Is there any way to change variable value without using setState() or notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I want to ask if there is any other way than using SetState() or notifyListener() to change the value of bool. Because using setState() or notifyListener() crashes app for some seconds. actually i m using NotificationListener to change the value of bool on user scroll. Please help

Comment: you should look for reason of app crashes after call setState() or notifyListener().

Comment: Actually i'm using FutureBuilder inside NotificationListeners and on user scroll i am changing value of bool... i figured out that app only crashed when setstate or notify listeners is called

Comment: Simply not using a method because it crashes your app is not the right way to approach it. Find out why it crashes your app. Try to figure out what exactly is happening. If necessary ask a question here regarding the specific crash, while providing enough details of the crash

Comment: @Ivo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028523/flutter-notificationlistener-crashed-app-for-some-seconds ....... here is a link to question i Asked yesterday, can you please check it? I also addeed a video of crash

Comment: use `ValueListenableBuilder` for example

Comment: @pskink i tried but exact same thing happened with that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use stream.it is like a pipe you add value from a side (Sink) and recieve it on the other side (Stream).i will try to explain it:

```
  //make a stream controller
  StreamController<bool> valueController = StreamController();
  
  //this will listen to every new value you add
  Stream valueOutput = valueController.stream;

  //you can add new values throw the sink
   Sink valueInput = valueController.sink;
```

so when you want to add a value to the stream just call

```
valueInput.add(true);//add whatever booleon value you want
```

and then recieve it by calling

```
 valueOutput.listen((value) {
   //this function will be invoked every time you add a new value.
 });
```

or you can add StreamBuilder if you want to rebuild a specific widget based on that boolean value

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: valueOutput,
      builder: (context,snapshot) {

       bool value = snapshot.data;
       log(value.toString());//true or false

       return yourWidget();
    })
```

i hope i explained it well, good luck with your problem.

i think when you use setState it rebuilds the entire screen and if you are using scroll controller to listen to user`s scroll then the screen will rebuild every pixel user scrolls so that is a lot of rendering.
maybe share some code snippet of your code so we can help.

Comment: Thanks for nice explaination brother, can we have a little meeting over zoom or google meet?